# Testando se uma String está dentro de um Arquivo .txt

Tags: python-3.x, comparação

Olá

Gostaria de saber como eu comparo uma string digitada pelo usuário com as strings contidas em um arquivo .txt

Minha ultima tentativa foi assim , mas não consegui o resultado que queria:

```
f = open("Testando.txt","r")
r = f.readline()
nome = input ("Digite qualquer coisa : ")
for line in r :
    if line == nome :
        print("já existe um nome igual")
    else :
        print("Obrigado pela nova interação")
input("Pressione em qualquer tecla para sair do programa")
f.close()*
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção de vocês. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O metodo `readline()` [devolve apenas uma linha do ficheiro](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), podias usar o `readlines()` que te devolve uma lista com todas, em que cada elemento é uma linha, ou com a maneira abaixo (usando um gerador):

```
nome = input ("Digite qualquer coisa : ")
with open('Testando.txt',  'r') as f:
    for line in f: # percorrer gerador
        if nome.lower() == line.lower().strip(): # retirar qubras de linha e comparar com ambas sendo minusculas
            print('já existe um nome igual')
            break
    else: # isto acontece se tivermos saido do for sem que tenha havido break 
        print("Obrigado pela nova interação")
input("Pressione em qualquer tecla para sair do programa")
```

Comment: Deu certo muito obrigado !! :)

Comment: De nada @SZJ08, ainda bem que resolveste